# PHP Headers remove cookies

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I've searched this question by google without success.. so I hope you can help me... I have two systems and I'm using a WS to connect then, I using PHP SOAP module.

The issue is, my request return an error because I'm sending cookies. (I don't set cookies in anywhere), but when I print the headers, there are cookies...

How can I prevent that?

```
POST /XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: &quot;http://schemas.erp2iecs.com/webservices/IsCompleted&quot;
Content-Length: 459
**Cookie: iECSAuth=;iECSAuth1=;**
```

Thanks!

```
public function connect()
    {
        global $db_process, $cfgGeneral;

        try
        {
            $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl,array('trace' => 1));

            // Namespace of the webservice
            $ns = 'http://schemas.erp2iecs.com/webservices'; 
            // Soap header information
            $headerbody = array('User' => $cfgGeneral['user'],'Password' => $cfgGeneral['pass']);
            // Creates the header
            $header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'Authentication', $headerbody);       
            // Set the Headers of Soap Client.
            $this->client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
        }
        catch(SoapFault $fault)
        {
            // Could not connect
            $this->_error[] = '0003 - Error connecting to SOAP server. Error Message: ' . $fault;
            $this->report_email("ofiraee_webservice_error", implode(" || ",$this->_error), true);
            return false;
        }   
    }

public function send_request($function, $xml, $parameter_name)
    {
        try
        {
            // Invokes the method ServerBeginImport and passes the XML above
            $paramsBody = array(trim($parameter_name)=>trim($xml));

            $result = $this->client->$function($paramsBody);

            $result_function = $function . "Result";
            $guid = $result->$result_function;

            return $guid;
        }
        catch(SoapFault $fault)
        {
            // Something wrong happened with this!
            $this->_error[] = '0004 - [ '.$function.'(); ] [ ' . $this->wsdl . ' ] [ SOAP HEADERS ' . $this->client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . ' ] [ SOAP RESPONSE ' . $this->client->__getLastResponse() . ' ] [ SOAP REQUEST ' . $this->client->__getLastRequest() . ' ] Error sending request. Error Message: ' . var_export($paramsBody, true) . $fault;
            $this->report_email("ofiraee_webservice_error", implode(" || ",$this->_error), true);
            $this->save_request($guid, $xml);

            return false;       
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would help if we knew how you were opening the SOAP request...

Comment: Is the resuest headers

Comment: @iam-decoder sorry you are right, I've updated the topic

Comment: if you explicitly define the 'Cookie' header as empty, does that help?

Comment: @iam-decoder how? :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85436/discussion-between-iam-decoder-and-pedro-monteiro).

Comment: look into [`SoapClient::__soapCall()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) you can input http headers that accompany the soap request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a soluction! To clear all cookies present in soap client object you just need unset($soapClient->_cookies); all cookies are removed!